# What would the singular of a tribes-people like Caledonii be?

Tags: vocabulary, declension, plural

This map names a lot of tribes-people. The one in Scotland is called **"Caledonii".**

[image]

I'm assuming "Caledonii" is the **plural form** of the people. I've also seen other maps where the **land** is called **"Caledonia"**. But what I want to know is, **what's the singular form when referring to just one person of the Caledonii?**

My English tendencies want to say "Caledonian", but English tendencies cannot necessarily be trusted, can they.

Answer (score 8):

*Caledonii* would be the tribes inhabiting *Caledonia*, the land. Think *Americans* and *America*. The word seems related to *Celt*, for what it's worth.

Grammatically, the singular would be *Caledonius*, but oddly, I cannot find Classical usage for this. It seems merely a descriptive adjective for geography/features of the land of Caledonia (such as "[Caledonian Ocean](http://www.theoi.com/Text/ValeriusFlaccus1.html)," "[Caledonian forest](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Florus/Epitome/1C*.html#XII)," and "[Caledonian bear](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/1294/1/7/144-153@1#7)").

It's possible to use *Caledonius* (for a male, *Caledonia* for a female) in this way, but I'm not so sure it was ever done.

I also see online the people called [*Caledones*](http://logeion.uchicago.edu/index.html#Caledones). Again, though, no singular. A similar search in the Thesaurus Linguae Graecae showed up no singular. By parallel with *Macedones* (as Rafael points out in the comments), though, one could perhaps use *Caledo* (-*onis*).

That's not to say you can't use *Caledonius*, though perhaps in Latin you'd want to use *vir Caledonius*.

For English, *Caledonian* would be acceptable, though apparently not for a modern Scot.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps we should ask from another angle. Italia exists for the land, so was there Italii? If so, what was the singular?

Comment: @DrZ214 If you want to go the analogy route, think *Gallia* > *Gallus, -i*.

Comment: Tacitus has "primo statim congressu ostendamus, quos sibi Caledonia viros seposuerit" (Tac. Agr. 31.4)

Comment: @brianpck So it's Gallia the land, Gallus (singular) and Gallusi (plural)? Shouldn't it be Gallii?

Comment: @DrZ214 The singular genitive and plural nominative of *Gallus* is *Galli*. When a word ends in *-us*, the *-i* (usually the genitive is given for declension) is implicitly assumed to replace *-us*. Similarly, we have *Italus* and *Itali*.

Comment: FWIW, I found "vir [Macedo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DMacedones)" in [Horace](https://books.google.cl/books?id=5NMGmoC94-0C&lpg=PA224&ots=WbE4tuVzNr&dq=vir%20macedonius&pg=PA224#v=onepage&q&f=false) (I cent. BC), and the [Acts of the Apostles 16](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_nt_actus-apostolorum_lt.html#16),9-12 (Greek I cent. AD/transl. IV AD)

Answer (score 5):

For whatever they might be worth, there are two inscriptions from Hadrian’s wall mentioning a centurion by the name of Caledonius Secundus, in both instances in the genitive singular.

https://romaninscriptionsofbritain.org/inscriptions/1854

https://romaninscriptionsofbritain.org/inscriptions/1679

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether 'Caledonii' can be used in the singular, but it would not be completely out of the ordinary if it can't.

In the Aeneid Virgil regularly describes the Greeks and Trojans as the 'Danai' and the 'Teucri' respectively. But he never uses them in the singular, or as an adjective.

So in your case, if you want to translate English into Latin, you could use 'vir Caledoniorum' to say 'a Caledonian man'; if by chance you're writing Latin verse, you might consider 'vir Caledonium', a common contraction which Virgil regularly uses.

Comment: Does Vergilius use *vir Dana(or)um/Teucr(or)um*? That would be interesting to see.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I don't think so; Vergilius often used the name of a Greek tribe as a pars pro toto adjective to describe the Greeks. Unfortunately I don't have time to look for any now, but I might if I have time later. But one example I know he uses is 'miles Dolopum', a soldier of the Dolopians which gives some support to my 'vir Caledonium' and his use of tribal names.

Comment: Can you add that to your answer? It'd make your point stronger.

Comment: While Vergil might not have referred to a single Greek with *Graecus*, Cicero, Livy, and Pliny all have.